# When should we use all three (trait, free-text and keywords) search strategies in a user-defined entity?

Tags: bots, wit.ai

I just came up with a tricky case that is blowing my mind. 
I'm using a 2 classic UsrDef entity (UDE) with free-text and keywords search strategies.

- Where can I find the **phone number** of **John Doe**?
- Where can I find the **office** of **Mark Zuckerberg**?

The one of interest is the one that captures *phone number, office, etc.* called typeInfo

Well, now I have the following expression:

- Where can I find **Isaac Newton**?

Mhh... no explicit typeInfo, but I want it to be treated as an intent to search Isaac Newton's **office** (typeInfo - office).

Should I add the 'trait' search strategy (having the three of them activated) to typeInfo?

I'll appreciate some light on this issue. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to have this entity be only a trait entity.

Given enough examples, wit should learn that the word "office" is what makes the entity value be "office", etc